# How can ı add value to nil object in swift

Tags: swift, xcode, class, oop, struct

I have issue about this code you see . Why its give me nil value and how can ı figure it out to right plz hep me

```
struct NilControl{
    var name:String?
}

var k: NilControl?

print(k)
// nil -> Okey ı guess just like that
k?.name = "name"

print(k?.name)
// nil -> ı expect to see name but its still give me nil
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See inline comments for an explanation of what's going on:

```
struct NilControl{
    var name:String?
}

var k: NilControl? //you've defined k as NilControl? and not assigned it a value yet

print(k) //this will be nil, since k has not been set

k = NilControl() //this sets k to have a value (ie not nil), but its `name` is still nil at this point
k?.name = "name"

print(k?.name) //will print Optional("name")
```

If you want to do some `nil` checking on it before printing the `name`, it might look something like this:

```
k = NilControl(name: "name") //this sets k to have a value & assigns a name

if let k = k, let name = k.name {
    print(name)
}
```

Comment: okey but ı wanna set values after ı define it.is it not possible? @jnpdx

Comment: My first example shows setting values (ie `name`) after you've defined `k`

Comment: thank you so much ı have understand where ı made mistake thanks to you . so as ı understand my problem is ı didnt init k so ı can not add value to k first ı need to initalize it then ı need to add some values.Am ı right ? @jnpdx

Comment: Yes, that's correct

Comment: thank you again bro :)  ı have checked your answer as correct @jnpdx